# How to achieve MVC pattern in sails?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js, modularity

I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve the MVC pattern is sails.js.

Now I have the following structure: I have a route which redirects the request to the controller:

```
'POST /api/user/...': {controller: 'UserController', action: 'someFunction'},
```

My user model:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    attributes: {...}
}
```

I have the controller:

```
someFunction: function(req, res) {
    let param = req.body.param;
    let userId = req.session.userId;
    userService.someFunction(userId, param, function (result) {
        return res.json({result});
    });
},
```

And in the userService I have methods for manipulating the database, for example:

```
someFunction: function(userId, param, callback){
    User.findOne(userId).exec(function (err, user){
                    if (err) {
                        callback(false);
                    } else {
                        // find the user's additional info
                        User.update({name: param}, { ... })
}
```

My real question is that is this a good pattern to follow or I'm on the wrong path.

Thanks for any kind of response.

Comment: The better question is, what are you trying to achieve? Why do you want MVC? There are other options out there too. You'll have to identify requirements and go from there.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a structure in my code. The MVC is the most familiar for me, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right in sails. This project will be quite big, so I'm trying to look forward and structure my code in the best possible way, so I'm open for any kind of structure, not only for MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Answer to this question can be opinion-based. Here is my opinion.

Sails project is scaffolded in MVC pattern. There are separate folders for Models (`api/models`), Controllers (`api/controllers`), and Views (`views`).

You're doing right thing having database methods in Services.
Anything that can be required by more than one controller action should go into services.

**Other thoughts:**

- Any logic which deals with a single model should be in that Model
- Prefer to apply constraints, foreign keys at database level as well
- With Node.js v7.6+, you can use `async/await`. Sails (Waterline) methods return Bluebird promises which works well with async/await.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to keep these in mind. ;)